# How to reverse onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I wanted to add inner shadow to a search box when the user clicks on it so I used this simple code :

```
function shadow()
{
document.getElementById("search2").style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)";
}
```

And the markup :

```
<input type="search" onClick="shadow()">
```

So that when you click on the search box, the "search2" div gets an inner shadow and it works.
But I want to know how to reverse this (remove the inner shadow) when the user unclick the search box and click elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Don't do what you're doing. Your click handler should simply add/remove a class which contains the styles. Or rather, `focus` and `blur` should add/remove respectively.

Comment: Unclick?  Do you mean releasing the mouse button, often called mouseUp?  Or do you mean clicking the mouse on anything other than the search box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `onfocus` and `onblur` events.

- `onfocus` - fires when the user is in the textbox
- `onblur` - fires when the user leaves the textbox

In the `onblur` event you add

```
document.getElementById("search2").style.boxShadow = "";
```

The click event only fires when the user clicks the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using any JavaScript at all, using the CSS [focus: pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afocus).  In your CSS styles, use this:

```
#search2:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

The advantage here is that it's less code and it will still work even in browsers without JavaScript enabled.  Here's a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5g9an/

It couldn't be simpler.  Well, I can't think of a simpler method, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `blur` event:

```
<input type="search" onClick="shadow()" onBlur="removeShadow()">

function removeShadow(){
  document.getElementById("search2").style.boxShadow="none";
}
```